# GatewayTimeout issue running stored procedure in logic app

Tags: azure, stored-procedures, azure-logic-apps, bad-gateway

We are facing an issue running three stored procedures (SPs) together using the Azure Logic Apps service and SQL databases.

Regardless of the run sequence of the SPs, the issue always shows up in the first SP that is run.

The processing initially used to take few seconds to run and execute successfully, but we noticed that the execution time and the required DTUs (database throughput units) were increasing day by day.

One of the SPs uses a variable that filters table `TABLE1` by date, and shows only the “current day” data in `TABLE2`.  The filter variable (used in the SP) is defined in the Logic App as `SUBSTRING(startOfDay(utcNow()), 0, 10)`,  which returns the current day value.

Our code consists of filtering the values of `TABLE1` for the current day only, put it in `TABLE2`, run some calculations on it and store the results back in `TABLE1`.  The `WITH`, `Last_Value`, `First_Value` and `INSERT` functions are used inside the SP code.  The `INSERT` function is used to insert the resulting rows into `TABLE1` (about ~74 rows).

The number of data rows recorded in `TABLE1` increases everyday but the number of data rows in `TABLE2` is constant since it is the result of filtering “current day”, so it only shows the current day's values.

Using SQL Server Management Studio, the SPs are manually executed without any problem.

At the beginning, when our database DTU was set to 400, the Logic App for the first SP was taking less than 10 minutes to execute, and the remaining two SPs took a few seconds each.

Lately the first SP is failing to execute, giving a GatewayTimeout error and the Logic Apps execution fails:

[image]

[image]

When we increased the DTU to 800, the Logic Apps runs successfully, but we still get a warning of GatewayTimeout.

[image]

The connection with the database was checked, the manual execution of each individual SP was tested, a change in the filter variable datatype from `datetime` to `varchar` (to match with the Logic Apps parameter) has been made, but the problem keeps occurring.

There is a tendency that this issue will recur if not solved. Any suggestions?

Thanks.

UPDATE

This is the code of one SP:

```
WITH enTotTable 
AS 
  (
    SELECT --TOP(100)
        se.id
        , se.gatewayName
        , se.deviceId
        , se.ts
        , se.pointNameId

        , case 
            when se.presentValue < 0 then 0 else se.presentValue end as presentValue
        , DATEPART(hh,se.ts) as hTs
    FROM dbo.SolarEnergyTable se
    WHERE se.gatewayName IN ('DPJW', 'DAN1') and se.pointNameId = 7 and not se.presentValue = 0 and se.ts >= @tsFilter
  ) 


, calculationTable AS
  (

    SELECT distinct
            FORMAT ( tot.ts , 'yyyy-MM-dd' ) as dayTs
            ,tot.deviceId
            ,tot.gatewayName

            , CASE 
                WHEN  Last_VALUE(tot.hTs) OVER(partition by tot.deviceId, DATEPART(dd, tot.ts)
                    ORDER by tot.hTs ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) 
                    - FIRST_VALUE(tot.hTs) OVER(partition by tot.deviceId, DATEPART(dd, tot.ts)
                    ORDER by tot.hTs ) >=12 
                then 1 
                Else NULL end as ifAllDay

            , CASE 
                WHEN  Last_VALUE(tot.hTs) OVER(partition by tot.deviceId, DATEPART(dd, tot.ts)
                    ORDER by tot.hTs ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) 
                    - FIRST_VALUE(tot.hTs) OVER(partition by tot.deviceId, DATEPART(dd, tot.ts)
                    ORDER by tot.hTs ) >=12 
                then (LAST_VALUE(tot.presentValue) OVER(partition by tot.deviceId, DAY(tot.ts)
                        ORDER by tot.deviceId desc, tot.ts
                        ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) 
                    - FIRST_VALUE(tot.presentValue) OVER(partition by tot.deviceId, DAY(tot.ts)
                        ORDER by tot.deviceId desc, tot.ts) )
                else NULL 
                end as enTdy

            ,case 
                when LAST_VALUE(tot.presentValue) OVER(partition by tot.deviceId, DAY(tot.ts)
                    ORDER by tot.deviceId desc, tot.ts
                    ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) < 0 then NULL

                else  
                    LAST_VALUE(tot.presentValue) OVER(partition by tot.deviceId, DAY(tot.ts)
                    ORDER by tot.deviceId desc, tot.ts
                    ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) 
                end as lastPvalueDay
            , case 
                when FIRST_VALUE(tot.presentValue) OVER(partition by tot.deviceId, DAY(tot.ts)
                    ORDER by tot.deviceId desc, tot.ts
                    ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) < 0 then NULL

                else 
                    FIRST_VALUE(tot.presentValue) OVER(partition by tot.deviceId, DAY(tot.ts)
                    ORDER by tot.deviceId desc, tot.ts) 
                end as firstPvalueDay            
    FROM enTotTable tot 
    WHERE not tot.presentValue = 0 
  )

, plantAndTdyTable 
AS
(   
    SELECT 
        tdy.gatewayName
        ,tdy.dayTs as ts
        ,CAST(2 as INT) as deviceId
        , CAST(20 as INT) as pointNameId
        , Case When 
            tdy.ifAllDay = 1 
            then SUM(tdy.lastPvalueDay)-SUM(tdy.firstPvalueDay)
            else NULL end as presentValue
    FROM calculationTable tdy
    GROUP BY tdy.dayTs ,tdy.ifAllDay, tdy.gatewayName
 UNION

    SELECT 
        tdy.gatewayName
        ,tdy.dayTs as ts
        ,CAST(2 as INT) as deviceId
        , CAST(17 as INT) as pointNameId
        ,SUM(tdy.lastPvalueDay) as presentValue
    FROM calculationTable tdy
    GROUP BY tdy.dayTs, tdy.gatewayName
 UNION


    SELECT 
        tdy.gatewayName
        , tdy.dayTs as ts
        , tdy.deviceId
        , CAST(6 as INT) as pointNameId
        , tdy.enTDY as presentValue
  From calculationTable tdy
  
)


INSERT INTO [dbo].[SolarEnergyTable]
SELECT 
    pt.gatewayName
    ,pt.ts
    ,pt.deviceId
    ,pt.pointNameId
    ,pt.presentValue
FROM plantAndTdyTable pt



-- SELECT *
-- From
-- plantAndTdyTable
-- -- calculationTable
-- -- enTotTable
```

Comment: Hi Jojoe, welcome to the site.  You will have to show the code for at least the SP that is causing problems.  Please post the code at the bottom of your question.  Users are more likely to answer questions that include code.  Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Sabuncu thank you for the message. I updated with the code of one SP.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the following answer [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/6019b299-cf39-447d-bc8d-aa365803b50b/running-a-stored-proc-manually-from-ssms-takes-16-minutes-running-it-with-logic-apps-takes-gt-12?forum=azurelogicapps):

[image]

I found it using [azure logic app stored procedure taking too long](http://azure%20logic%20app%20stored%20procedure%20taking%20too%20long).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So I can’t do much except  increase the time out of the logic app

Comment: @Jojoe Well, that's just a work-around.  Azure experts will know the reason for the slow down.  Have you tried contacting Azure support?  I have found them to be incredibly helpful on Twitter: https://twitter.com/AzureSupport?ref_src=twsrc%5Egoogle%7Ctwcamp%5Eserp%7Ctwgr%5Eauthor

Answer (score 0):

I finally change my architecture for running my SPs. To avoid GatewayTimeout of the Logic app when he need to connect to the database, I use the azure automation account. I created a PowerShell script to run my SPs and use the Logic App to run the PowerShell Script. It works better in my case.

Answer (score 0):

You can do retry policy setting in logic app itself. This setting is also useful for handling timeout issue 504.

[image]